Variation of Constants formula with derivative operator
The Variation of Constants formula for an equation of the form $\partial_t u = A u + f$ is given by
$$
u(t) = T(t)u_0 + \int_0^t T(t-s)f(s) \, ds,
$$
where $(T(t))_{t\geq0}$ is the semigroup generated by $A$. For the application with respect to the operator $A := \partial_x^2 + \text{Id}$ I'm having difficulties. The usual choice for the $T(t)$ is $e^{At}$, but in the course manual for the subject I'm following it is mentioned that derivative operators are usually unbounded, in which case $e^{At} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k A^k}{k!}$ does not converge.
My inuition in the field of functional analysis is very limited so I'm kind of stuck here at the moment, does anyone know a way to work around this problem and give a definition to $T(t)$? Thanks in advance!

A is either $-i\partial_x+\dots$ or $-\partial_x^2+\dots$ resulting in bounded exponentials.

@RolandF thanks! that helps for intuition! however unfortunately the question is posed with $A = \partial_x^2+...$, do you know if ther is a way to work around this unboudedness?

Sorry, must be $+\partial_x^2$.  $f  (-\Delta_{xx} f)$, the adjoint of $(\nabla_x f)^2 $ is a positive operator. So in $\partial_t f = \partial_{x,x} f $ the right side is negative in Hilbert space.

@RolandF thanks for your reply! I only don't see yet how i could use this in my problem. Apologies for my lack of understanding, I'm relatively new to this area of mathematics

Take a look at Heat kernel.
